# foreach looping on first object only

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I cant seem to find why my foreach loop is stuck on the first entry I guess. It only brings back one object of an array N times. I checked the response and it does have more then 1 object in an array. Im not sure what I´m doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
 if (!empty($response) || !(isset($response[0]->errors))) {

    $responseproduct = new StdClass;
    $variant = new StdClass;
    $responseproducts = array();

    foreach ($response->products as $product) {

        $variants = array();

        $responseproduct->id = $product->id;
        $responseproduct->name = $product->title;
        $responseproduct->urlimg = $product->images[0]->src;

        foreach ($product->variants as $variantobj) {
            $variant->variantid = $variantobj->id;
            $variant->price = $variantobj->price;
            $variant->title = $variantobj->option1;
            $variant->urlcheckout =  "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/".$variant->variantid.":1?ref=kindeu-ads";
            array_push($variants, $variant);
        }

        $responseproduct->variants = $variants;

        array_push($responseproducts, $responseproduct);

    }

    $jsonResponse = array(
        'success' => 'Llamada exitosa.',
        'producto' => $responseproducts
    );

    // Replace the response body with the json encoded data
    return json_encode($jsonResponse);


}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for the help in advance :D

Here is what it prints:

```
{
  "success": "Llamada exitosa.",
  "producto": [
    {
      "id": 97477842,
      "name": "Enfapro Premium Etapa 2",
      "urlimg": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula_enfapro_premium_e3.jpg?v=1343083756",
      "variants": [
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 97477842,
      "name": "Enfapro Premium Etapa 2",
      "urlimg": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula_enfapro_premium_e3.jpg?v=1343083756",
      "variants": [
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 97477842,
      "name": "Enfapro Premium Etapa 2",
      "urlimg": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula_enfapro_premium_e3.jpg?v=1343083756",
      "variants": [
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 97477842,
      "name": "Enfapro Premium Etapa 2",
      "urlimg": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula_enfapro_premium_e3.jpg?v=1343083756",
      "variants": [
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 97477842,
      "name": "Enfapro Premium Etapa 2",
      "urlimg": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula_enfapro_premium_e3.jpg?v=1343083756",
      "variants": [
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 97477842,
      "name": "Enfapro Premium Etapa 2",
      "urlimg": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula_enfapro_premium_e3.jpg?v=1343083756",
      "variants": [
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 97477842,
      "name": "Enfapro Premium Etapa 2",
      "urlimg": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula_enfapro_premium_e3.jpg?v=1343083756",
      "variants": [
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 97477842,
      "name": "Enfapro Premium Etapa 2",
      "urlimg": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula_enfapro_premium_e3.jpg?v=1343083756",
      "variants": [
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 97477842,
      "name": "Enfapro Premium Etapa 2",
      "urlimg": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula_enfapro_premium_e3.jpg?v=1343083756",
      "variants": [
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 97477842,
      "name": "Enfapro Premium Etapa 2",
      "urlimg": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula_enfapro_premium_e3.jpg?v=1343083756",
      "variants": [
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        },
        {
          "variantid": 322904189,
          "price": "445.00",
          "title": "1.2kg.",
          "urlcheckout": "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/322904189:1?ref=kindeu-ads"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the $response:

```
{
  "success": "Llamada exitosa.",
  "producto": {
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 97477928,
        "title": "Enfagrow Premium Etapa 3",
        "variants": [
          {
            "id": 259621536,
            "product_id": 97477928,
            "title": "400gr.",
            "price": "101.00",
            "sku": "737763",
            "position": 1,
            "grams": 400,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option1": "400gr.",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2012-12-03T13:06:59-06:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-09-04T10:54:34-05:00",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": false,
            "barcode": null,
            "inventory_quantity": 101,
            "old_inventory_quantity": 101,
            "image_id": 193648526,
            "weight": 0.4,
            "weight_unit": "kg"
          },
          {
            "id": 228143764,
            "product_id": 97477928,
            "title": "800gr.",
            "price": "216.00",
            "sku": "737771",
            "position": 2,
            "grams": 900,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option1": "800gr.",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2012-07-23T17:35:47-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-09-04T10:54:34-05:00",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": false,
            "barcode": null,
            "inventory_quantity": 89,
            "old_inventory_quantity": 89,
            "image_id": 193648526,
            "weight": 0.9,
            "weight_unit": "kg"
          },
          {
            "id": 322904443,
            "product_id": 97477928,
            "title": "1.2kg.",
            "price": "318.00",
            "sku": "788112",
            "position": 3,
            "grams": 1200,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option1": "1.2kg.",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2013-06-10T10:21:57-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-09-04T10:54:35-05:00",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": false,
            "barcode": null,
            "inventory_quantity": 90,
            "old_inventory_quantity": 90,
            "image_id": 193648526,
            "weight": 1.2,
            "weight_unit": "kg"
          }
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "id": 193648526,
            "product_id": 97477928,
            "position": 1,
            "created_at": "2012-07-23T17:51:24-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2012-07-23T17:51:24-05:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula-enfagrow-premium-3_900_grs.jpg?v=1343083884",
            "variant_ids": [
              228143764,
              259621536,
              322904443
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 215105273,
        "title": "Enfagrow Premium Etapa 3 - Sabor Vainilla",
        "variants": [
          {
            "id": 485161409,
            "product_id": 215105273,
            "title": "800gr.",
            "price": "235.00",
            "sku": "737771",
            "position": 1,
            "grams": 900,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option1": "800gr.",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2014-01-15T18:03:29-06:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-09-04T10:54:35-05:00",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": false,
            "barcode": null,
            "inventory_quantity": 106,
            "old_inventory_quantity": 106,
            "image_id": 440133777,
            "weight": 0.9,
            "weight_unit": "kg"
          },
          {
            "id": 485161417,
            "product_id": 215105273,
            "title": "400gr.",
            "price": "115.00",
            "sku": "737763",
            "position": 2,
            "grams": 400,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option1": "400gr.",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2014-01-15T18:03:29-06:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-09-04T10:54:36-05:00",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": false,
            "barcode": null,
            "inventory_quantity": 102,
            "old_inventory_quantity": 102,
            "image_id": 440133777,
            "weight": 0.4,
            "weight_unit": "kg"
          },
          {
            "id": 485161425,
            "product_id": 215105273,
            "title": "1.2kg.",
            "price": "335.00",
            "sku": "788112",
            "position": 3,
            "grams": 1200,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option1": "1.2kg.",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2014-01-15T18:03:29-06:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-09-04T10:54:37-05:00",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": false,
            "barcode": null,
            "inventory_quantity": 101,
            "old_inventory_quantity": 101,
            "image_id": 440133777,
            "weight": 1.2,
            "weight_unit": "kg"
          }
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "id": 440133777,
            "product_id": 215105273,
            "position": 1,
            "created_at": "2014-01-15T18:03:30-06:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-02-05T15:57:53-06:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula-enfagrow-premium-3_900_grs_b9e50ef2-354e-452c-9727-13d192460e64.jpg?v=1423173473",
            "variant_ids": [
              485161409,
              485161417,
              485161425
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 136214925,
        "title": "Enfamil A.R. Premium",
        "variants": [
          {
            "id": 311269687,
            "product_id": 136214925,
            "title": "900gr.",
            "price": "434.00",
            "sku": "569348",
            "position": 1,
            "grams": 900,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option1": "900gr.",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2013-05-16T10:02:53-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-09-04T10:54:37-05:00",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": false,
            "barcode": null,
            "inventory_quantity": 107,
            "old_inventory_quantity": 107,
            "image_id": 265850921,
            "weight": 0.9,
            "weight_unit": "kg"
          },
          {
            "id": 311269689,
            "product_id": 136214925,
            "title": "400gr.",
            "price": "203.00",
            "sku": "569321",
            "position": 2,
            "grams": 400,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option1": "400gr.",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2013-05-16T10:02:53-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-09-04T10:54:38-05:00",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": false,
            "barcode": null,
            "inventory_quantity": 110,
            "old_inventory_quantity": 110,
            "image_id": 265850921,
            "weight": 0.4,
            "weight_unit": "kg"
          }
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "id": 265850921,
            "product_id": 136214925,
            "position": 1,
            "created_at": "2013-05-16T10:05:48-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2013-05-16T10:05:48-05:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/formula_enfamil_premium_a.r.jpg?v=1368716748",
            "variant_ids": [
              311269687,
              311269689
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 291704225,
        "title": "Enfamil Nutramigen Premium con LGG",
        "variants": [
          {
            "id": 688773553,
            "product_id": 291704225,
            "title": "357gr",
            "price": "290.00",
            "sku": "804847",
            "position": 1,
            "grams": 400,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": null,
            "option1": "357gr",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2014-04-15T17:16:25-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-09-07T16:57:07-05:00",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": false,
            "barcode": "",
            "inventory_quantity": -4,
            "old_inventory_quantity": -4,
            "image_id": 717861481,
            "weight": 0.4,
            "weight_unit": "kg"
          }
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "id": 717861481,
            "product_id": 291704225,
            "position": 1,
            "created_at": "2014-04-16T11:18:15-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2014-04-16T11:18:15-05:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/feature_nutramigen_premium_llg.png?v=1397665095",
            "variant_ids": [
              688773553
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 136215519,
        "title": "Enfamil Premium Confort 400gr.",
        "variants": [
          {
            "id": 311272317,
            "product_id": 136215519,
            "title": "400gr.",
            "price": "215.00",
            "sku": "903124",
            "position": 1,
            "grams": 400,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option1": "400gr.",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2013-05-16T10:15:51-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-09-04T10:54:39-05:00",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": false,
            "barcode": null,
            "inventory_quantity": 100,
            "old_inventory_quantity": 100,
            "image_id": 265861561,
            "weight": 0.4,
            "weight_unit": "kg"
          }
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "id": 265861561,
            "product_id": 136215519,
            "position": 1,
            "created_at": "2013-05-16T10:37:59-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2013-05-16T10:37:59-05:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/Enfamil_Confort.jpg?v=1368718679",
            "variant_ids": [
              311272317
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 136220823,
        "title": "Enfamil Premium EnfaCare",
        "variants": [
          {
            "id": 311286757,
            "product_id": 136220823,
            "title": "363 gr.",
            "price": "180.00",
            "sku": "949760",
            "position": 1,
            "grams": 400,
            "inventory_policy": "deny",
            "compare_at_price": null,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "inventory_management": "shopify",
            "option1": "363 gr.",
            "option2": null,
            "option3": null,
            "created_at": "2013-05-16T10:46:08-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2015-09-04T10:54:39-05:00",
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "taxable": false,
            "barcode": null,
            "inventory_quantity": 83,
            "old_inventory_quantity": 83,
            "image_id": 265872599,
            "weight": 0.4,
            "weight_unit": "kg"
          }
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "id": 265872599,
            "product_id": 136220823,
            "position": 1,
            "created_at": "2013-05-16T10:57:47-05:00",
            "updated_at": "2013-05-16T10:57:47-05:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/enfamil-enfacare-premium.jpg?v=1368719867",
            "variant_ids": [
              311286757
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($variants)`?

Comment: And also the `$response`

Comment: The response is cut in half cause of too many characters D:
edit: But the number of times it prints is the same as the number of products the response is bringing me

Comment: So you want to retrieve all the products of `Llamada exitosa`?

Comment: What do you want to be the expected output? Just the first index only.

Comment: I want to take out the information I need(id,name,etc) from each of the objects in the array response. Not success but on "producto"

Comment: Try my answer. If that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it,

Somehow the variables on the object I was "repopulating" each loop, wasnt saving the new variable each loop.... dunno why. If someone could explain why this happened. It was only getting the last loop for each and every one of the objects I put on the array. I only re set the variable which was holding the response before pushing it to the final array value. Here is the code:

```
if (!empty($response) || !(isset($response[0]->errors))) {

    $variant = new StdClass;
    $responseproducts = array();

    foreach ($response->products as $product) {

        $variants = array();
        //I just re set the variable responseproduct inside the loop instead of outside. This variables was holding the value for each of the loops.
        $responseproduct = new StdClass;

        $responseproduct->id = $product->id;
        $responseproduct->name = $product->title;
        $responseproduct->urlimg = $product->images[0]->src;

        foreach ($product->variants as $variantobj) {
            $variant->variantid = $variantobj->id;
            $variant->price = $variantobj->price;
            $variant->title = $variantobj->option1;
            $variant->urlcheckout =  "http://bebe2go.myshopify.com/cart/".$variant->variantid.":1?ref=kindeu-ads";
            array_push($variants, $variant);
        }

        $responseproduct->variants = $variants;

        array_push($responseproducts, $responseproduct);

    }

    $jsonResponse = array(
        'success' => 'Llamada exitosa.',
        'producto' => $responseproducts
    );

    // Replace the response body with the json encoded data
    return json_encode($jsonResponse);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

For **$response**

```
$informations= [];

 foreach($response->producto as $key => $val)
 {
   $informations[] = $val;
 }
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($informations);
```

And for **$variants**

```
$variants_info = [];

 foreach($variants->producto as $key => $val)
 {
   $variants_info[] = $val;
 }
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($variants_info);
```